# Using Javascript to create/store cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to create a simple cookie using javascript . But for some reason , `json.stringify` doesnt seem to work

i have the below object

```
var text = JSON.stringify({username: req.user.username})
```

which i send back as the cookie

```
res.cookie('user',text)
```

however , the client side stores the cookie in this format

```
user=%7B%22username%22%3A%22Kannaj%22%7D
```

how do i escape the '%' characters and store it as a stringified JS object?

Comment: The `%` characters **are** escape sequences. The storage is fine. You just need to unescape it when you want to read the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

```
decodeURIComponent('%7B%22username%22%3A%22Kannaj%22%7D')
//returns
'{"username":"Kannaj"}'
```

As noted by Quentin:

> The storage is fine. You just need to unescape it when you want to read the data

Comment: Could i do this on the server side?

Comment: Nope, it's a protocol thing, you can unescape on client

Comment: @VatsalPathak __Replaces each escape sequence in the encoded URI component with the character that it represents.__ So yeah, it only returns strings, as only strings has replace method

Answer (score 0):

Use [decodeURLComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent), it accepts an encoded component of a Uniform Resource Identifier.

```
decodeURIComponent("JavaScript_%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D1%8B");
// "JavaScript_шеллы"
```